# rsocket - RDMA API - unable to use SOCK_DGRAM option

Tags: sockets, rdma

i instantiated rsocket object, it fails with error of 'no such file or directory' .

```
rsocket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)
```

how to use function rsendto/rrecvfrom if i cannot has a udp rsocket object?

centos7.7, rdma : 52mlnx1-1.52104

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SOCK_DGRAM`?

Comment: sorry, type error, SOCK_DGRAM still fails